# Turn duplicate rows in pandas dataframe into new columns in the same dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a large list of dataframe with duplicate observations for the same index, analagous to the 'df' below:

```
import pandas as pd
boxes = {'Color': ['Red','Orange','Yellow','Green','Red','Orange','Yellow','Green','Red','Orange','Yellow','Green'],
     'Shape': ['Square','Square','Square','Rectangle','Rectangle','Rectangle','Square','Rectangle','Circle','Circle','Circle','Circle'],
    'Length': [15,25,25,15,15,15,20,25,26,26,23,29],
     'Width': [8,5,5,4,8,8,5,4,2,2,3,5,],
    'Height': [30,35,35,40,30,35,40,40,36,35,39,46]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(boxes, columns = ['Color','Shape','Length','Width','Height'])


desired_boxes = {'Color': ['Red','Orange','Yellow','Green'],'Shape1': ['Square','Square','Square','Rectangle',],
    'Length1': [15,25,25,15], 'Width1': [8,5,5,4],'Height1': [30,35,35,40],'Shape2': ['Rectangle','Rectangle','Square','Rectangle'],
    'Length2': [15,15,20,25],'Width2': [8,8,5,4], 'Height2': [30,35,40,40], 'Shape3':['Circle','Circle','Circle','Circle'],
    'Length3': [26,26,23,29], 'Width3': [2,2,3,5,],'Height3': [36,35,39,46]}

desired_df=pd.DataFrame(desired_boxes,columns=['Color','Shape1','Length1','Width1','Height1','Shape2','Length2','Width2','Height2',
    'Shape3','Length3','Width3','Height3'])
```

[image: df]
**df**

[image: desired_df] **desired_df**

I am trying to sort through the dataframe based on a column ('Color' here) and create new columns of the data associated with a duplicate color. See desired_df for clarity.

Column names don't necessarily need to change, but I think they might have to in order to preserve different data from a column of a duplicate name. Here is a column name forloop from another post:

```
count=1
cols = []
for column in df.columns:
    if column == 'Shape':
        cols.append(f'Shape_{count}')
        count+=1
        continue
df.columns = cols
```

And here is a loop for trying to merge duplicate dataframes into the original:

```
for value in df:
    separate_i=df[df['Color'].duplicated()]
    df=df.merge(separate_i, on='Color', how='inner')
    i+=1
```

I am fairly new to coding so I apologize for the poor attempts at this, I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreaciated! Thanks.

Comment: Changing your data structure to this form seems like a bad idea. Is there any specific reason you want to move it to this format?

Comment: It is for environmental samples which will be mapped later based on a single lat/long value associated with a specific sample, but the same sample has several different metal measurements associated with it, but prints out vertically like in the example df. The ultimate goal is to get all metal measurements for one sample within one labelled row, so in this example all the different kinds of red shapes into one row with the attached details... does that answer your question?

Comment: Yeah I think so. Does this mean that there will be a varying amount of duplicates for each sample, with lots of nan values? Have you considered using booleans for each specific shape, indicating whether or not they are present?

Comment: ```df.groupby('Color').apply(lambda df_: df_[['Shape','Length','Width','Height']].values.flatten()).apply(pd.Series).reset_index()```

Comment: For columns you can do something like: ```df_desired.columns = ['Shape'] + ['Shape','Length','Width','Height']*df.a.value_counts().max()```

Comment: Thanks! the df.groupby('Color') code worked, I am still struggling with column naming. I hadn't considered booleans because some 'duplicate' rows will be all filled (have values for all the metals) and some will have NaNs, and I figured it'd be just as easy to change NaNs to 0's at the end.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing for the columns, which is ugly but works for now

`list = ['Shape','Length','Width','Height']`
`a=len(df.axes[1])-1`
`b=a/4`
`list4 = list*int(b)`
`c = ['Colors']`
`names = c+list4`
`df=df.set_axis(names, axis=1)`